# Murugan shrinking body?

Tags: shiva, moksha

Siddhar Boganathar mentioned in one of his poems that Murugan went through the  process of shrinking and dissolving to attain final liberation.

Does this have any written references?

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the name of the poem, it's link, book or the source where you read it?

Comment: Unfortunately, all I know is a quote from Ramalinga Vallalār, but cannot find the source!

Comment: Oh! I see, so you have just heard it orally not read it? That's sad.

Comment: Was a quote about talking the rainbow body

Comment: You can share the quote in the question, would make a comparitively better question. Also, since you do know that it is in a poem, have you searched in the available poems of Boganathar already? Usually in stack exchange the questioner has to do some research their own selves (*which you already may know since you are an old member*)  as well to make a good question which can be answered. As in just like the answerer, it must also seem to us that you have made some effort on your end too.

Comment: True, but I didn't found anything so fare hence asking. Will continue and update eventually